# Rails 4 .joins() issue -- not working

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Model for Plugin:

```
class Plugin < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :vulns
end
```

Model for Vuln:

```
class Vuln < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plugin
end
```

Table for Plugin:

```
create_table "plugins", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
end
```

Table for Vuln:

```
create_table "vulns", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "title"
    t.integer "plugin_id"
    t.string  "vulnerability_type"
    t.string  "fixed_in"
end
```

When I use rails console using `rails c` and enter `Plugin.select("*").joins(:vulns)` it only grabs data from the Plugin table

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Plugin id: 1, name: "xxx">, #<Plugin id: 2, name: "xxx">
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `plugins` INNER JOIN `vulns` ON `vulns`.`plugin_id` = `plugins`.`id`
```

However, when I execute this query in mysql, it shows all content from vulns and plugins like its supposed to. For every plugin there is atleast one or more vuln in the database.

**So here's the question:** How do I get it to fetch content from both tables (plugins and vulns) instead of just plugins?

Comment: Basically rails return attributes only from LEFT(FIRST) table as array of duplicable objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vulns` values are there, it's just not shown because you are using `Plugin` model to select, i.e. `Plugin.select("*").joins(:vulns)`.

If you did the following, you will get the value:

```
> plugin = Plugin.select("*").joins(:vulns)
> plugin.first.title 
=> "mytitle"
```

Because you are querying through `Plugin` model, you'll see `Plugin` object.

Another way to test this would be by doing the following:

```
> plugin = Plugin.select([:name, :title]).joins(:vulns)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Plugin id: 1, name: "xxxx">]>

# It won't show you title even though it's there
> plugin.title
=> "mytitle"
```